# nobody Vs anybody Vs. nobody in a specific context

Tags: idiomatic-language

How to ask from a friend to not tell something / to keep something something in secret?

If I want to choose between these two, which is natural or idiomatic?

> Please, don't tell it to **anybody**.
>
> Please, don't tell it to **anyone**.
>
> Please, tell it to **nobody**.

Comment: You could also drop the "it to" if you wanted.

Comment: As AIQ notes, most people would simply say: **Please don't tell anybody/anyone** or **Please tell nobody/no-one**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these sentences read fine (natural and idiomatic). They differ slightly in formality and register. "Anyone" and "anybody" are interchangeable in most cases, with "anyone" being a little more formal-sounding than "anybody". Also in certain phrases one sounds better than the other. For example, people say "anyone else" more commonly than "anybody else".

> Please, tell it to nobody.

This sounds more emphatic. In certain contexts "nobody" is considered informal.